# read data from file with c++

Tags: c++, pointers, substr

I have to do the following only with char *:

```
try{
    streampos begin,end;        
    char delimeter[3] = {',', '\n', '\0'};
    int numChars = 0, tmpNumChars = 0;
    int pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, startIndex = 0;
    ifstream file("Students.txt", ios::in);
    if (!file) throw MyExceptions();
    begin = file.tellg();
    file.seekg (0, ios::end);
    end = file.tellg();
    int size =  end - begin;
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);        
    char charField[size];
    while(file.getline(charField, size, '\n'))
    { 
        char *tmpCharField = charField;
        while(*tmpCharField != '\0'){
            numChars++;
            tmpCharField++;
        }
        tmpNumChars = numChars;
        while(tmpNumChars > 0){
            tmpCharField--;
            tmpNumChars--;
        }

        CustomString tmpStudent(tmpCharField, numChars);  
        pos1 = tmpStudent.findCharacter(&delimeter[0], startIndex);
        CustomString tmpStudentCode = tmpStudent.subString(startIndex, pos1);
        pos2 = tmpStudent.findCharacter(&delimeter[0], (pos1 + 1));
        CustomString tmpFirstName = tmpStudent.subString((pos1 + 1), pos2);
        pos3 = tmpStudent.findCharacter(&delimeter[2], (pos2 + 1));
        CustomString tmpSecondName = tmpStudent.subString((pos2 + 1), pos3);
        startIndex = pos3 + 1;
    }

    file.close();   
}catch(MyExceptions e){

}
```

**This is the FindCharacter() Method:**

```
//Find_first_of() implementation
int CustomString::findCharacter(char *symbol, int pos){
char *tmpCandidateString = this->CandidateString;
for (int i = pos; i < this->NumberOfChars; i++){
    if ((tmpCandidateString[i] == (*symbol)) || (tmpCandidateString[i] == EOF)) return i;
}
return 0;
}
```

**The file is something like that:**

```
kokokoko1,kokokoko2,kokokoko3
kokokoko4,kokokoko5,kokokoko6
kokokoko7,kokokoko8,kokokoko9
```

When I read the kokokoko3 the delimeter array or *symbol on FindCharacter() reads '\n' whis is ok, either something '\nd', which is strange, or all the times does not find the the \n or \0 character where it is called later on the program. Also how can I find the EOF (read the kokokoko9) with the above implementation?

Please do not say to me to use the already Methods or to use strings, I can't use strings and their Methods. It is an assignment...

Comment: Any C++ course that fails to teach `std::string` is one you're just going to have to forget and unlearn later. Sadly this is all too common.

Comment: This code is really cluttered and hard to follow. What is the problem you're trying to solve? `'\nd'` is not a thing.

Comment: The debugger show sometimes '\nd' and I was wondering why? We learnt many things for string and their methods but on this assignment we have to do only with pointers.Any help?

Comment: Maybe it's showing you what's at the `char*` destination. If there's no `d` in your input, though, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: sounds like you have a non \0 terminated string

Comment: `findCharacter` should take a `const char` arg, not `char*`, which implies it's working with C strings, and it's not. You have to constantly dereference that pointer for no reason.

Comment: *"I have to do the following only with char *: [code]"* -- presenting code is a bad way to specify project requirements, especially when the code is not yet complete. This question would be improved if you described what you have to do.

Comment: Yes but the documentation says that getline(char *, int, delimeter) adds an extra \0 to the end

Comment: Simple read a txt file with the above records only with char *, that is the assignment

Comment: I don't understand why you would size a character array to hold the entire file and then read into the array line by line. Sure, you've made absolutely certain the buffer is big enough, but man. Wasting a lot of memory except in the edge case where the whole file is one line. Suggestion: If you gotta do it this way, read the whole file into the array and then `strtok` the sucker.

Comment: Warning: `char charField[size];` non Standard code that can easily lead to a stack overflow with a large file.

Comment: Warning `file.getline(charField, size, '\n')` will never place an EOF character into the string. `getline` stops dead and null terminates when it finds the end of the file. That makes `if ((tmpCandidateString[i] == (*symbol)) || (tmpCandidateString[i] == EOF))` a bit iffy.

Comment: Yes thanks for your replies, i was able to make it run. I know the risks of this code but the instructor has to understand if we are able to work only with pointers